# Seaborn : How to get the count in y axis for distplot using PairGrid

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using PairGrid but I don't understand what does y axis means for distplot. I thought it represents a count. But it's starting from negative values in the pairgrid. If I make only the distplot, I'm getting the count.

I don't know if it's clear so, there's some plots :

My PairGrid:

[image: My PairGrid]

My distplot :

[image: Distplot]

The distplot is the same as the plot in the top left corner of the PairGrid.

The code corresponding to this is :

```
sns.distplot(pd.DataFrame(mySerie), kde=False)
```

and for the PairGrid :

```
g = sns.PairGrid(myDataFrame)
g = g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use both methods to see a different trend in the data in respect to the range of values and the total count.
See below to get a better idea on what I was working for when I came across your question, (sorry not sharing data itself that is too big).
with KDE false I can see that the amount of Yes is twice as much as No in the total count.
Instead with KDE True I can see that at lower ranges of values the No is predominant and even higher in % over the Yes category.
Hope it will help...

```
kde=False
```

[kde=False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6h2k.png)

```
kde=True
```

[kde=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH6zm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It was understanding (although I could be mistaken) that the y-axis in your histograms is the fraction of the total counts. For example, in my distplot, roughly 0.08 or 8% of rows are in the 0-5 bin
[My Distplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw2pC.png)